# mid-sentence wildcard in php xpath

Tags: php, xpath

I working with an API that returns employees working on a project.

The workers are delivered in the following format

```
<projects>
    <project>
        <field name="employee1_id" format="Long">1</field>
        <field name="employee1_name" format="string">Bob</field>
        <field name="employee2_id" format="Long">2</field>
        <field name="employee2_name" format="string">Ben</field>
        <field name="employee3_id" format="Long">3</field>
        <field name="employee3_name" format="string">Bill</field>
    </project>
</projects>
```

How can i use a wildcard to find all employee-ids and omitting any other field that does not end with `_id`? I've seen functions that uses `contains` and `start-with`, but non of them can help me.

I've tried `$object->xpath('field[@name="employee*_id"]')` but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [PHP doesn't have XPath 2.0 support](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/205580/129666), you can't use `matches` or `ends-with` to make this particular query easy. However, there is a work-around using `substring` and `string-length`:

```
/projects/project/field[starts-with(@name, 'employee') and substring(@name, string-length(@name) - string-length('_id') + 1) = '_id']
```

This says "give me all `field` that start with `employee` and end with `_id`." In the wild you may encounter undesirable matches (eg, "employees_id"), but for the sample data, this works. [Demo.](https://3v4l.org/H44aU)

Were PHP ever to have XPath 2.0, then this expression would match your need:

```
/projects/project/field[matches(@name, 'employee\d+_id')]
```

Comment: My bad, there is several fields that starts with employee1_, but im only interested in _id. I've updated the question. Is it possible to combine with ends-with?

Comment: `ends-with` is XPath 2.0. However, there is a workaround. Update forthcoming.

Comment: There you go, this works again with the sample data.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you